# Get folder path from local machine to execute process of other application on button click of windows application

Tags: c#, .net, process, checkboxlist

How to give specific folder path to start process using C#.Net code?

I have written following code to start the my another application exe(i.e. "ConsoleApplication1.exe") which is stored at (D:) drive of PC.

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkListBox.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    if ((string)chkListBox.Items[i] == "ConsoleApplication1")
    {
        string path = @"D:\TAS\Development\Latest\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug";
        string files = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path);
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
               FileName = path+chkListBox.Items[i].ToString()+".exe"
            }
        };
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

When Clicked on Button then I got following exception:
 Exception:

---

---

Comment: Nothing shows up in your "Exception" section...

Comment: You can drop the `files` variable, you don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few potential problems with the code you posted. It's hard to know what your current problem is without seeing the exception, but I think this is the most likely issue:

On the line `FileName = path+chkListBox.Items[i].ToString()+".exe"`, you appear to be missing a path separator.

Use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of manual string concatenation to combine paths. By using `Path.Combine`, you eliminate a whole category of mistakes that can be made when combining two strings to make a new path.

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
       FileName = Path.Combine(path, chkListBox.Items[i].ToString()+".exe");
    }
};
```

Comment: ex = {"The system cannot find the file specified"}